# Странное закрытие приложения Qt5

Tags: c++, qt5

Пишу программу (под windows), и столкнулся вот с какой странной ситуацией ... Есть таблица, ее редактирую вызывая свой диалог редактирования посредством обычного `dialog->exec()`. Все работает как часы.

Но понадобилось программу прятать в трэйбар. Написал код, программа прячется. Пытаюсь из меню в трэйбаре вызвать диалог создания записи в таблице. Полностью тот же код, о котором я написал выше. Вызывается диалог. Так вот проблема - после закрытия диалога закрывается и программа! И по `Ok`, и по `Cancel` диалога.

Пол-дня убил на отладку, но так и не нашел причину.

**Но случайно нашел вот что:**

```
void MainWindow::SlotTest() {
  TRACE_CALL
  Data["FirstName"] = "T";
  Data["LastName"] = "TEST";
  Data["CardNumber"] = "1234567890";
  show();           // <------------------------
  activateWindow(); // <------------------------
  emit SigSendData(&Data);
}
```

Если вставить эти две команды (выделил комментами), то до открытия диалога редактирования всплывает основное окно ... И дальше все работает без ошибок!

Не понимаю!!! Как-так? Почему если главное окно спрятано, происходит такая ситуация?

Answer (score 4):

Нашел решение проблемы!

В `main.cpp` нужно добавить строчку, сразу же за `QApplication a(argc, argv);` вот такую:

```
a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

Это предотвращает автоматическое закрытие приложения, если видимых окон не осталось.